# How to add PHP variable value to Between Query

Tags: php, mysql

Below is my query

```
public function total_registration_month($from1,$to1){

    $q = $this->link->prepare('SELECT advisor, COUNT(*) as total
        FROM
        (
                SELECT advisor 
                FROM training_details 
                WHERE ndate BETWEEN $from1 AND $to1 
            UNION ALL
                SELECT advisor 
                FROM student_details 
                WHERE registereddate 
                BETWEEN $from1 AND $to1
        ) AS advisor
        GROUP BY advisor');

    $q->execute();

    $count = $q->fetchall();

    return $count;

}
```

How Can I add tht passed from1 and to1 value into Between from date and to date.If I apply variable direclty or with single quite Its showing error.Kindly help me anyone.

Comment: You're  using `prepare` but not actually making use of it. Read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php). There are plenty of examples of how to do this properly, which will also fix your problem.

Comment: Are you using the `PDO` or `mysqli_` database access API?

Comment: Im using PDO database access

Comment: I assumed PDO since mysqli doesn't have a fetchall method.

Comment: I just doubted with the declaration of variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using PDO you should also be using Parameterized queries like this

```
public function total_registration_month($from1,$to1){

    $q = $this->link->prepare('SELECT advisor, COUNT(*) as total
                                FROM
                                (
                                        SELECT advisor 
                                        FROM training_details 
                                        WHERE ndate BETWEEN :fromd AND :tod 
                                    UNION ALL
                                        SELECT advisor 
                                        FROM student_details 
                                        WHERE registereddate BETWEEN :fromd1 AND :tod1
                                ) AS advisor
                                GROUP BY advisor');

    $params = array(':fromd' => $from1,':tod' => $to1,
                    ':fromd1' => $from1,':tod1' => $to1);

    $res = $q->execute($params);
    if ( ! $res ) {
        print_r( $q->errorInfo() );
        exit;
    }

    $count = $q->fetchall();
    return $count;
}
```

This also removes all the issues of how to concatenate data into your query, as it is all looked after by PDO, and also removes any SQL Injection issues with data received from the user

Answer (score 0):

```
public function total_registration_month($from1,$to1){

        $q = $this->link->prepare("SELECT advisor, COUNT(*) as total
        FROM
        (
                SELECT advisor 
                FROM training_details 
                WHERE ndate BETWEEN '$from1' AND '$to1' 
            UNION ALL
                SELECT advisor 
                FROM student_details 
                WHERE registereddate 
                BETWEEN '$from1' AND '$to1'
        ) AS advisor
        GROUP BY advisor");
        $q->execute();

        $count = $q->fetchall();

        return $count;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With a PDO connection please try the below codes:

```
$q = $this->link->prepare('SELECT advisor, COUNT(*) as total
    FROM
    (
            SELECT advisor 
            FROM training_details 
            WHERE ndate BETWEEN ? AND ? 
        UNION ALL
            SELECT advisor 
            FROM student_details 
            WHERE registereddate 
            BETWEEN ? AND ?
    ) AS advisor
    GROUP BY advisor');

$q->execute(array($from1,$to1,$from1,$to1));

$count = $q->fetchall();
```

Notice the '?' (question mark) in the sql query.